# SOLR full-import not working when running using lynx command

Tags: solr, data-import, lynx

I want to setup a cron in Amazon EC2 Linux to run a SOLR full-import at 12:15AM every night.
Before I setup the cron I tried testing in the terminal whether it is working or not. I used below command to test

```
/usr/bin/lynx http://amzon-instance-ip:8983/solr/work/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Output of the command:

```
[1] 15153
```

But when I go to below url to check whether the full-import actully initiated. I see the full-import command is not running.
http://amzon-instance-ip:8983/solr/#/workb/dataimport//dataimport

Anyone can help me why the SOLR full-import not running with lynx command? Am I using lynx correctly or do I need to use a differnt approach? Any Suggestions please.

Comment: Can you use wget?

Comment: @Oyeme, thanks for your suggestion. I came up with two solutions and posted them below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time on internet searching the solution for why a url not working with lynx but could not find the solution.
Thanks for @Oyeme  suggestion, I got two ways to get my URL running using linux curl and wget commands.

Using linux `curl` command:

```
curl -s ' http://amzon-instance-ip:8983/solr/work/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false' > /dev/null
```

Using linux `wget` command:

```
wget -O /dev/null ' http://amzon-instance-ip:8983/solr/work/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false'
```